# how to create a image slider with help of only HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create a slider with HTML and CSS? 
if yes than how to create a slider using HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following link. it is very simple and easy to understand
http://qnimate.com/creating-a-slider-using-html-and-css-only/

Answer (score 6):

yes try this code . here is a link [Simple css slider](http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi)

html code

```css
@-webkit-keyframes slidy {
    0% { left: 0%; }
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
}
@keyframes slidy {
    0% { left: 0%; }
    20% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
}
div#slider figure img {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
div#slider figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 10s slidy infinite;
  /* change this time to reduce time*/
  -webkit-animation: 10s slidy infinite;
  /* change this time to reduce time*/
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/austin-fireworks.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/taj-mahal.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/ibiza.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/ankor-wat.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/austin-fireworks.jpg" alt="">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: what if I wanted to add some notes along with the images, like image is on the left and the bunch of text is on right.this pair makes one slide like this three more slides. is it possible?

Comment: Something like this, I couldnt do it but I am trying to slide one after another https://codepen.io/gladwin-james/pen/qBqRxKw is it possible? with in that gray area itself